# NSMutableArray not printing correct data - iOS/Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling to get my array to print the correct data.

I've got it linked to a button, so it gets the textfield data and adds it to a Person class which has a subclass called PhoneBookEntry which contains firstName, and then adds it to an NSMutableArray called entries. here's the button code:

```
PhonebookEntry *person = [[PhonebookEntry alloc] init];

self.firstName.text = person.firstName;

[self.entries addObject:person];


NSLog(@"%@", self.entries);
```

Here's the start where I initialise everything:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) PhonebookEntry *person;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *entries;

@end
```

in my viewDidLoad, this is the code to create the NSArray.

```
self.entries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
```

I've tested and it works fine when adding normally and prints etc, just not with the array.

Thanks

The output

```
test,
test2,
"<PhonebookEntry: 0x8c69770>"
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to show when you print the data?

Comment: I'm wanting it to show whatever I typed into the textfield, 
so eg. Timothy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is printing correctly.

Actually you want something more from your code or Objective-C.

For this you need to **override description in `PhonebookEntry` class** to break to the level where NSLog can print. NSLog can't print `person` object values.

```
-(NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, could you give an example? thanks

Comment: I am saying if you do `NSLog(@"%@", self.entries);` it will not print as you wish to see. Implement the above method in you PhonebookEntry class. then you will see the result quite good. NOTE: I use only firstName and lastName, you can change the string as per you PhonebookEntry model and its properties.

Answer (score 2):

This `self.firstName.text = person.firstName;` should be the other way around, so change it to this:

```
person.firstName = self.firstName.text;
```

Comment: I've changed that around and I'm getting the same result.

I've changed it to addObject:person.firstName. and it works fine, but I need to be able to add all of the data into the array (firstname,last name and phone number) as I'll be editing and deleting by index etc.) any other ideas?

Comment: Good one, I gave an answer saying override the `description` method, by overlooking the code. You eyes are good to catch the issue :)

Comment: Look at @AnoopVaidya's answer too and combine mine with his